# how to store different values in every tab (firefox extension)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Im making firefox extension. One function stores value in every tab, to use it later by other function.

```
function setValue(value) {

   var attr = gBrowser.document.createAttribute("value");

   attr.value = value;

   gBrowser.document.attributes.setNamedItem(attr);

};



function getValue() {

  var attr = gBrowser.document.attributes.getNamedItem("value");

  if (attr != undefined && attr != null)

    return attr.value;

  else

    return null;

};
```

For some reason, this doesn't work.  Can you spot an error in my code?
Function getValue() should get value of active tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more errors than code here:

- There's no `gBrowser.document` - you probably meant `gBrowser.ownerDocument` or just `document` (equivalent but simpler).
- Neither is `gBrowser.document.attributes`, you meant `gBrowser.attributes`.
- Using `attributes` seems very weird, an equivalent to the fixed up version of your code would be `gBrowser.setAttribute("value", value)` and `gBrowser.getAttribute("value")`
- The fixed up code still isn't what you probably need and you didn't specify what exactly do you need (`gBrowser.mCurrentTab.setAttribute`?)

Comment: Instead of using attributes, you can also just use Javascript properties, because in Javascript (unlike, say, Java) you're always free to just attach new properties to an object: `gBrowser.value = 'someValue'` (assuming that 'value' doesn't already have some meaning -- you'd have to check.)